# Call function from a custom file with parameters

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

How to call a function from a custom external file and also to be able to have parameters?

The external file is an XML file. The tags looks like this:

```xml
<menu name="bar">
        <option func="boo">Execute Me</option>
        <option func="foo" params="a, b, c, d">I want parameters</option>        
</menu>
```

I want execute a function defined in the `func` attribute. I have built the code to parse everything, I only need to call it. The problem is I need to call it from a class that will be imported in another file.
like this:

```
 class xmlParser:
   def __init__(self, filepath, funcname, *params):
      # code to parse data etc.      
        exec_func_from_file(funcname, params)


   def exec_func_from_file(self, *args):
        # code to call function.
        ...
        ...
        funcname(params)
```

Next I want to have a class/module to hold all functions to be executed

```
class functions:
   def __init__(self):
       pass

   def boo(self):
       print "Well done"

   def foo(self, a, b, c, d):
     print 'Executed'
```

And then it will be another which it will use the class like this.

```
 import xmlParser
 import functions

 filepath = 'files/test.xml' 

 if var1 == var2: 
   params = 'stored from somewhere' 
   xmlParser(filepath, 'foo', *params)
 else:
   xmlParser(filepath, 'boo', *params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class xmlParser:
   def __init__(self, filepath, funcname, *args):
        # code to parse data etc.
        exec_func_from_file(funcname, args)

   def exec_func_from_file(self, funcname, *args):
        # code to call function.
        ...
        ...
        functionsobj = functions() # do you really need a class for this?
        funcobj = getattr(functionsobj, funcname)
        funcname(*args)
```

Comment: Thanks I have figured out how to do it starting from your example. I really appreciate your help man. Cheers!